# trying to calculate and print the mean and its returning as a <function at> rather than a number? PYTHON

Tags: python

I have my program in python and I have used an external file with numbers in, I created a list for the numbers to be stored in and then I need to find the mean, standard deviation and the length of the list from this, at the moment my program looks like this:

```
data = open( "gauss.dat", "r" )
numbers=[]

for line in data: 
    numbers.append(line)

sorted(numbers)

def length(numbers):
    length = len(numbers)
    return length

def mean(numbers):
    sum = 0
    for element in numbers:
        sum += element

    mean = sum/length
    return (mean)

def main():
    global history

    print (length)
    print('The smallest number is ' + numbers[0])
    print ('The largest number is ' + numbers[-1])
    print(mean)    
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

When I run the program

1. It doesn't sort the numbers correctly? I am new to python so I don't know if there is an obvious error
2. It prints out the mean and length as `< function length at 0x039475B0 >`, `< function mean at 0x03947630 >`. I have no idea how to change this into a number?

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**regarding 1)**

A powerfull tool: the interactive shell combined with the `help`-command:

```
>>> help(sorted)

Help on built-in function sorted in module __builtin__:

sorted(...)
    sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
```

So we need either

```
numbers = sorted(numbers)
```

or

```
numbers.sort()
```

(see `help(numbers.sort)` for details)

**regarding 2)**

as stated by mgilson: you have to invoke the function:

```
print(mean(numbers))
```

**regarding comment**

with

```
for line in data: 
    numbers.append(line)
```

you read the file line-by-line as a *string*. But to do some calculations, you need a numeric type. One way to do this would be:

```
for line in data: 
    numbers.append(float(line))
```

This converts the text in `line` into a floating type. Leading or trailing spaces are cropped (at least in my python-interpreter) but you may run into trouble with empty or erroneous lines.

Comment: regarding 2) When i change print(mean) to print(mean(numbers)) I now get a type error 
'line 34, in mean
    sum += element
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str''

Comment: I have extended my awnser, I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thank-you, it solves one problem but creates another as i have to state the first and last number in the list, and i cannot do this if i convert the lines to a float.

Comment: You have to convert the float-value back to a string. E.g. `print('The smallest number is ' + str(numbers[0]))` or, if you want some control about the format: `print('The smallest number is %g' % numbers[0])`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *call* the function `length` and/or `mean` :

```
print(length(numbers))
print(mean(numbers))
```

In python, functions are objects themselves.  So they have a representation that gets printed.  You can assign them to different names in your current namespace, pass them to other functions, etc.  e.g.

```
MeAn = mean  # This is a violation of PEP 8!
print(MeAn(numbers))  #same as `print(mean(numbers))`
```

In other words, when you tell python:

```
print(mean)
```

It prints information *about the function object* `mean`.  It doesn't run the function however, so there is no way to get at it's return value (After all, how should it know what to use as input arguments?)

Comment: when I change print(mean) to print(mean(numbers)) I get another problem, 'line 35, in mean
    sum += element
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str''

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` returns sorted version of iterable, but doesn't change it, you need one of those:

```
numbers = sorted(numbers)
```

or:

```
numbers.sort()
```

About functions, you need to call them, with necessary arguments - eg:

```
mean = sum/length(numbers)
```

You have this bug in several places in your code.

Comment: So whenever I want to use the mean, eg in standard deviation, will i have to use mean(numbers) ?